# C++: undefined reference to `xxx`

Tags: c++, g++

I have a project, and the directory structure is:

```
.
├── bin
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── blocking_deque
│   │   └── blocking_deque.hpp
│   ├── buffer
│   │   ├── buffer.cpp
│   │   └── buffer.h
│   ├── epoller
│   │   ├── epoller.cpp
│   │   └── epoller.h
│   └── log
│       ├── log.cpp
│       └── log.h
└── test
    ├── Makefile
    └── test_log.cpp
```

*log.h*:

```cpp
#ifndef LOG_H
#define LOG_H

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include "../blocking_deque/blocking_deque.hpp"
#include "../buffer/buffer.h"

class Log {
public:
    // ...
    bool is_open();
    // ...
private:
    Log();
    virtual ~Log();

    // ...
    Buffer buf;
    // ...
};

#endif // LOG_H
```

*log.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "log.h"

Log::Log() {
// ...
}

Log::~Log() {
// ...
}

inline bool Log::is_open() {
// ...
}
```

*buffer.h*:

```cpp
#ifndef BUFFER_H
#define BUFFER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <atomic>

class Buffer {
// ...
};

#endif // BUFFER_H
```

*buffer.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <sys/uio.h>  // readv
#include <unistd.h>   // write
#include <cerrno>     // errno
#include <cassert>    // assert
#include <algorithm>  // copy
#include "buffer.h"

// ... definition of some members of Buffer
```

*blocking_deque.hpp*:

```cpp
#ifndef BLOCKING_DEQUE_HPP
#define BLOCKING_DEQUE_HPP

#include <deque>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

template <typename T>
class BlockingDeque {
// ...
};

// ... definition of some members
```

*test_log.cpp*:

```cpp
#include "../src/log/log.h"


void test_log() {
    using level_type = Log::level_type;
    Log::get_instance()->init(1, "./test_log1", ".log", 0);
    int cnt = 0;
    for (level_type lv=3; lv>=0; --lv) {
        Log::get_instance()->set_level(lv);
        for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i) {
            for (level_type new_lv=0; new_lv<=3; ++new_lv) {
                LOG_BASE(new_lv, "%s ===== %d", "test", cnt++);
            }
        }
    }
    Log::get_instance()->init(1, "./test_log2", ".log", 5000);
    cnt = 0;
    for (level_type lv=0; lv<=3; ++lv) {
        Log::get_instance()->set_level(lv);
        for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i) {
            for (level_type new_lv=3; new_lv>=0; --new_lv) {
                LOG_BASE(new_lv, "%s ==== %d", "test", cnt++);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    test_log();
}
```

When I use `g++ -g test/test_log.cpp src/blocking_deque/blocking_deque.hpp src/buffer/buffer.cpp src/log/log.cpp -o ./a`, the compiler(specifically, it's the linker) informs me that **undefined reference to `some function`**. The detail is shown below:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3lAVRd.o: in function `test_log()':
/home/fansuregrin/workshop/my_http_server/test/test_log.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Log::is_open()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fansuregrin/workshop/my_http_server/test/test_log.cpp:28: undefined reference to `Log::is_open()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccnM4HDs.o: in function `Log::write(int, char const*, ...)':
/home/fansuregrin/workshop/my_http_server/src/log/log.cpp:167: undefined reference to `Buffer::has_written(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, the `Log::is_open()` is defined in `src/log/log.cpp`, the `Buffer::has_written(unsigned long)` is defined in `src/buffer/buffer.cpp`. Why it can't be compiled?

*==============================*

**The reason for the problem is `inline`!**
**After I removed the `inline`s affixed to `Log::is_open` and `Buffer::has_written`, then there is no error.**

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: You went a little to minimal with your example, we can't compile this ourselves.  Also, in your compile command you have `src/blocking_deque/blocking_deque.hpp`, which you should not be doing.  only source files should be compiled, not header files

Comment: Coming back to the headers: These are `#include`d by the source files which is what the compiler makes aware of them...

Comment: Why did you declare `is_open` as `inline`? That's the problem. If you tried to express "a hint to compiler that this function should be inlined", remove it. Compilers have been ignoring that for the past 20 years, they are better than you at optimising 99% of the time. If you want to define it in header, move it to header and keep inline, if you want to define it in .cpp, remove `inline`.

Comment: Just for the case you're not aware: `inline` has a new meaning in C++ since C++11, it is *not* a hint (any more) to do function inlining, but instead tells the compiler to translate the function only once even if seen within multiple translation units. This is only relevant for functions defined in headers.

Comment: The problem is the `inline`! After I removed the `inline`s affixed to `Log::is_open` and `Buffer::has_written`, then there is no error.